# react-native-image-picker showImagePicker text colors

Tags: react-native, imagepicker

this is react-native-image-picker  ImagePicker.showImagePicker

and in my device i use dark mode and it ended up like this. i cant change the text color and i dont know how. anyone can help me?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- In `node_modules` > `react-native-image-picker` > `android` > `src` > `main` > `res` > `layout` > `list_item.xml`
- In line :

```
android:textColor="change color this"
```

I do this work.

I answer at [github](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1677#issuecomment-1279491298)